# Can you use Oracle ADF with IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, ios, intellij-idea, compatibility, oracle-adf

I know that IntelliJ Idea can interact with Android devices, but with an Oracle ADF interface could it interact with iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle ADF is designed to be code in Oracle Jdevelopper IDE. IntelliJ Idea isn't supported.

To build an Oracle ADF program on iOS or Android, you have to use Oracle Mobile Application Framework (the mobile development version of ADF) : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html

Comment: There is a plugin for eclipse to enable some kind of weird support for ADF. It's called OEP for Eclipse aka "Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse".

Comment: I used it, you have to add manually all the binding that are usually designed to be created by jDevelopper. The pain !